# Google Map cannot be navigated

Tags: android, google-maps

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    String fontPath = "fonts/roboto-bold.ttf";
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_map);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), fontPath);
    appname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWelcomeMap);
    appname.setText("Cavite Map");
    appname.setTypeface(tf);
    appname.setTextSize(30);
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                requestCode);
        dialog.show();
        return;
    }
    MapFragment mp = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.the_map);
    manilaMap = mp.getMap();
    manilaMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    manilaMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    manilaMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService("location");
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location currentLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    LatLng manilaLatLng = new LatLng(14.282837, 120.964441);
    manilaMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(manilaLatLng));
    manilaMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
    if (currentLoc != null) {
        onLocationChanged(currentLoc);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 200, 0, this);
    manilaMarkers();
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    LatLng manilaLatLng = new LatLng(14.282837, 120.964441);
    manilaMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(manilaLatLng));
    manilaMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

}
```

- How can I make it to navigate all parts of the map ?

This code only display where you input the coordinates and when I want to change it by scrolling and zooming it goes back where it is.

Answer (score 0):

the map is navigable in your code, the problem of "going back to it" is because you have the camera change when a new user location is retrieved.
You put 200 and 0 as min time (ms) and min distance, so updates are frequent.
You have two option, either increase those values (but map will go back anyway), or remove the camera change when location changes automatically, just change your "onLocationChanged" function to:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    LatLng manilaLatLng = new LatLng(14.282837, 120.964441);
    //manilaMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(manilaLatLng));
    //manilaMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

}
```

Comment: I tried to remove them but when i first load the map , it's not going to the designated location. Is there any other way that it will not go back at the same time it automatically navigates to my designated location ?

Comment: what you mean for "it is not going to the designated location"? Which location? In your onCreate function you have the position manilaLatLng and then you move there. It is not clear from your question what you want to achieve. Do you want the app to follow the user movements? Or Zoom to a fixed location and then allow interaction freely?

Comment: Thanks for responding sir , as you can see I set the location (14.282835, 120.964441) but still doesn't going in that coordinates, I think there's something wrong in other parts of the program.

Comment: it's going in the ocean part and the method is for displaying markers to my map. I'll try this in the real device with internet connection because I'm just using emulator , I think it's the problem . I'll reply here for the progress , anyway you are a big help :) thanks , Another question , are you pro handling 2d arrays ? this is my another problem

Comment: it is going in the ocean because you are using "getLastKnownLocation". That method can give you 0,0 as position or NULL, having your app crashing. You should check fused location provider for obtaining user location